# getElementById value not working

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass a value from javascript to a field on a form.  However, it doesn't seem to work.  The html code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="splitter()">
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
    <form name="myform" action="http://localhost:8080/EfsiDatabase/timer"
          method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete">
      <input type="hidden" name="index" id="index">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the javascript file, the issue I am having is the last line where I am trying to assign the value to the index input field.  No value returns when I do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function splitter() 
{
    var str=window.location.search;
    var replaced=str.replace("?entry=","");
    var n=replaced.split("&entry=");
    var i=0;
    var form = document.forms['myform'];
    while(n)
    {
       var x=n[i].split("%7C%7C");

       var e1 = document.createElement("input");
       e1.type = "hidden";
       e1.name = "staff"+i;
       e1.value = x[0];
       var e2 = document.createElement("input");
       e2.type = "hidden";
       e2.name = "date"+i;
       e2.value = x[1];
       var e3 = document.createElement("input");
       e3.type = "hidden";
       e3.name = "project"+i;
       e3.value = x[2];
       var e4 = document.createElement("input");
       e4.type = "hidden";
       e4.name = "task"+i;
       e4.value = x[3];
       var e5 = document.createElement("input");
       e5.type = "hidden";
       e5.name = "notes"+i;
       e5.value = x[4];
       var e6 = document.createElement("input");
       e6.type = "hidden";
       e6.name = "hours"+i;
       e6.value = x[5];

       form.appendChild(e1);
       form.appendChild(e2);
       form.appendChild(e3);
       form.appendChild(e4);
       form.appendChild(e5);
       form.appendChild(e6);
       i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("index").value=i+1;
}
</script>
```

How can I get a value with this method?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "no value returns"?  The element with `id="index"` is a hidden field.  Did you check for script errors?

Comment: You have `while(n)` but you never change the value of `n` inside the loop. If you get it to work otherwise, that'll be an infinite loop.

Comment: He means he isn't receiving its value on the back end.

Comment: And if you replace `"?entry="`  by `""` you can't split afterwards by `"&entry"`, as long as you don't have two "entry" on the query string.

Comment: I checked it and the loops is not the issue as n is an array.  I am trying to count how many times the loop is run.  I am using i as a counter and trying to return i to the index form field.

Comment: But you don't change `n`. This is not a `foreach`. As far as I can see your `while` should loop infinite or not even one time, depending on what the split did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
while(n)
{
    var x=n[i].split("%7C%7C");
    // ...
}
```

Please use below code:

```
while(n[i])
{
    var x=n[i].split("%7C%7C");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Linus Thanks for the Beautify

Comment: @user2464576, no problem! I love to help, especially when someone else posts the answer. ;-)